# And how is the step from XBMC to the console?

Tags: openelec, terminal

Cannot access the console in OpenELEC.
Does someone know a way?

Answer (score -1):

OpenELEC does not provide a console. Switch to Raspbmc or xBian

Comment: you cann ssh to it via root@raspberryip with password 'openelec'